# Prove that $A'\cap B=B\Longleftrightarrow A\subseteq B'$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove that $A'\cap B = B\Longleftrightarrow A\subseteq B'$

**Attempt**: First, let  $x\in A\subseteq B'$ . If  $x\in A'\cap B$, then   $x\in A'$  and  $x\in B$ ...

Conversely, assume  $x\in A \subseteq B'$ . Therefore,  $x\in A$ and  $x\in B'$, i.e.  $x\notin B$ ...

**Question**: Is it correct to let some $x$ be in each side of the proof to prove it because it seems to lead me to a dead end.
If not, please suggest a new way to prove this. Thank you!

Comment: Consider adding the elementary-set-theory tag so that people can find your problem more easily.

Comment: Hint: $A'\cap B = B \iff B \subset A' \iff A \subset B'$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to prove that $$A^C \cap B = B \Longleftrightarrow A \subseteq B^C$$

$\Longrightarrow$

$$x\in A \Longrightarrow x \not \in A^C \Longrightarrow x\not\in A^C \cap B \Longrightarrow x\not\in B \Longrightarrow x\in B^C$$

$\Longleftarrow$

Let's do this by double containment, that is, $$A^C \cap B \subseteq B \quad \wedge \quad B \subseteq A^C \cap B$$ It is obvious that $A^C \cap B \subseteq B$, (it is basic property). The interesing one is $B \subseteq A^C \cap B$.

Let's supose, to arrive at a contradiction, that $B \not \subseteq A^C \cap B$, that is, it exists $x\in B$ such that $x \not \in A^C \cap B$ $$x \not \in A^C \cap B \Longrightarrow \neg (x \in  A^C \cap B) \Longrightarrow \neg (x \in  A^C \wedge x \in B) \Longrightarrow  x \not\in  A^C \vee  x \not\in B $$ So, we have that $$\exists x\in B \wedge(x \not\in  A^C \vee  x \not\in B)$$

Case $1)$. $x \in B$ and x $\not \in B$ which is clearly a contradiction.

Case $2)$. $x \in B$ and x $\not \in A^C$ which implies that $x \not\in B^C$ and x $\in A$ which is a contradiction to our hypothesis, because we have that $A\subseteq B^C$.

The contradiction comes of suposing that $B \not \subseteq A^C \cap B$, then $B \subseteq A^C \cap B$ and $A^C \cap B \subseteq B$ which implies that $A^C \cap B = B$.

Therefore, $$A^C \cap B = B \Longleftrightarrow A \subseteq B^C$$

Answer (score 2):

You're right that your arguments don't work, because they don't really go anywhere. You should be very clear about what you're supposed to prove, and what you're allowed to assume. Once you get that down pat, then usually the arguments have basically written themselves.

The first thing to notice is that you are proving an equivalence (which we can see from the $\iff$). This means that we will need two arguments: a $\implies$ argument and a $\impliedby$ argument (once you're more confident, it may be possible to combine these arguments into one, but don't run before you can walk).

Let's look at the $\implies$ argument. What you have to prove is:
$$A \subseteq B'.$$
You are allowed to assume that $A' \cap B = B$, but for now, it's best to focus on what you're trying to accomplish. How do you prove a subset relation like this? You should start by assuming that we have an element $x$ of $A$, and then logic our way into concluding that $x$ is an element of $B'$, which is to say, $x \notin B$.

I usually find it helpful to do this: to lay out what I'm trying to prove, filling in both the start ("Suppose $x \in A$...") and the end of my argument ("... therefore $x \notin B$, i.e. $x \in B'$"). This gives me a useful framework to fill in. Remember too that this is only the $\implies$ direction, and another argument is required for the $\impliedby$ direction.

So, let's suppose that $x \in A$. We are assuming that $A' \cap B = B$, and I want to use this fact to help us say something about $x$ with respect to $B$. So, my big idea is to take the complement of both sides of this equality. By De Morgan's laws:
$$B' = (A' \cap B)' = (A')' \cup B' = A \cup B'.$$
Now, since $x \in A$, we have $x \in A \cup B'$, since $A \subseteq A \cup B'$. But then, this set is $B'$, so $x \in B'$. And, this is what we wanted to conclude. In particular, this means that $A \subseteq B'$, as required (which finishes the $\implies$ direction).

I'll set up the other direction for you, and leave you to fill it in. This time, we wish to prove
$$A' \cap B = B.$$
To prove this set equality, you'll need to prove two things:

- $A' \cap B \subseteq B$ (this should be easy to show),
- $B \subseteq A' \cap B$ (this will be the majority of the argument).

To show the second point, your argument will start like "Suppose $x \in B$...", and should end like "... Therefore, $x \in A' \cap B$"). At some point, you should use the fact that $A \subseteq B'$, i.e. every point in $A$ is also in $B'$. Give it a go.

Comment: +1 for the amazing intuition and insight!

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Thanks! It's nothing that a decade of tutoring experience won't yield. :-)